# DataFrame in pandas, group and aggregate in the same row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to generate differentes column from row.

This is my code:

```
d = {'PARENT_PART': ['KRC161262', 'KRC161262', 'KRC161833', 'KRC161834', 'KRC161834'], 'CITY': ['BARCELONA', 'MADRID', 'BARCELONA', 'BARCELONA', 'MADRID'], 'GOOD_OR_FAULTY': ['GOOD', 'GOOD', 'GOOD','GOOD','FAULT']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

grouped1 = df.groupby(['PARENT_PART', 'CITY']).size().reset_index(name='counts')

for index, row in grouped1.iterrows():    
    ciudad = row['CITY']    
    codigo = row['PARENT_PART']
    counts = grouped1.loc[(grouped1['PARENT_PART'] == codigo) & (grouped1['CITY'] == ciudad), 'counts'].values[0]
    df.loc[index, ciudad] = counts
print(df)
```

With this code I obtain that:

```
  PARENT_PART       CITY GOOD_OR_FAULTY  BARCELONA  MADRID
0   KRC161262  BARCELONA           GOOD        1.0     NaN
1   KRC161262     MADRID           GOOD        NaN     1.0
2   KRC161833  BARCELONA           GOOD        1.0     NaN
3   KRC161834  BARCELONA           GOOD        1.0     NaN
4   KRC161834     MADRID          FAULT        NaN     1.0
```

My objetive is, for each PARENT_PART repeated, create a new column with the CITY and add 1 (like counter).

My expected result:

```
  PARENT_PART  GOOD_OR_FAULTY  BARCELONA  MADRID
0   KRC161262  GOOD            1.0        1.0
2   KRC161833  GOOD            1.0        NaN
3   KRC161834  GOOD            1.0        1.0
```

Comment: Is it expected that MADRID for KRC161834 gets a 1 even if it was FAULT?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/07_reshape_table_layout.html?highlight=pivot#pivot-table)? Particularly the `aggfunc` option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can get the first part with [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
pd.crosstab([df['PARENT_PART'], df['GOOD_OR_FAULTY']], df['CITY']).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
CITY PARENT_PART GOOD_OR_FAULTY  BARCELONA  MADRID
0      KRC161262           GOOD          1       1
1      KRC161833           GOOD          1       0
2      KRC161834          FAULT          0       1
3      KRC161834           GOOD          1       0
```

Or [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
(df.assign(value=1)
   .pivot_table(index=['PARENT_PART', 'GOOD_OR_FAULTY'], columns='CITY', values='value')
)
```

Output:

```
CITY PARENT_PART GOOD_OR_FAULTY  BARCELONA  MADRID
0      KRC161262           GOOD        1.0     1.0
1      KRC161833           GOOD        1.0     NaN
2      KRC161834          FAULT        NaN     1.0
3      KRC161834           GOOD        1.0     NaN
```

If you further want to aggregate:

```
agg = {k: 'sum' for k in df['CITY'].unique()}
agg['GOOD_OR_FAULTY'] = '/'.join

(pd.crosstab([df['PARENT_PART'], df['GOOD_OR_FAULTY']], df['CITY']).reset_index()
   .groupby(['PARENT_PART'], as_index=False).agg(agg)
)
```

Output:

```
CITY PARENT_PART  BARCELONA  MADRID GOOD_OR_FAULTY
0      KRC161262        1.0     1.0           GOOD
1      KRC161833        1.0     0.0           GOOD
2      KRC161834        1.0     1.0     FAULT/GOOD
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pivot table for that:

```
df_pivot = df.pivot_table(
    index='PARENT_PART', 
    columns='CITY', 
    values='GOOD_OR_FAULTY', 
    aggfunc='count'
).reset_index()

CITY PARENT_PART  BARCELONA  MADRID
0      KRC161262        1.0     1.0
1      KRC161833        1.0     NaN
2      KRC161834        1.0     1.0
```